# Como realizar busca em uma tabela mysql com dois filtros?

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo uma página onde ela retorna uma tabela do meu banco de dados, mas como essa tabela recebe vários dados estou tentando montar um filtro para ela, fiz um form e a partir dele um filtro, segue exemplo:

```
$busca1 = $_POST['input001'];

if ($busca1 != "") 
{
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$busca1'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sqli) or die("Erro ao retornar dados");

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {   
        echo "<tr><td>".$registro["Coluna1"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna2"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna3"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Colun4"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna5"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna6"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna7"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna8"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna9"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna10"] . "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna11"]. "</td><td>". $registro["Coluna12"] ."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Agora queria saber como fazer para buscar juntando dois campos, seria algo como `if ($busca1 != "" && busca2 != "")` e daí repetir para todas as possibilidades ou existe uma forma melhor e com menos repetição de código?

Comment: eae Natã resolveu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Busca simples

```
 caso um condição dependa da outra
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$busca1' AND column3 = '$busca3' ";
 caso seja idependentes uma da outra
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$busca1' OR column3 = '$busca3' ";
```

## Busca avançada um pouco mais rapida

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1,2,3,4) ";
```

com array,

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$arr = implode(',', array_map('intval', $arr));
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1,2,3,4) ";
```